# I have a problem with this simple raindrop array program

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, push

I am trying to make the code so that every time `yPositions` array `[0]` hits the value of `400`, the program will:

- create a new raindrop array that falls down at a randomized `xPositions` value
- reset the value of `yPositions[0]` to 0

I am also trying to make it so that when other arrays are created, their `yPositions` value wont reset to "0". I want them to have an independent reset when their `yPositions` array value hits 400.

Right now the only thing that is happening is:

- The first raindrop falls down and resets `yPositions` at the value of 400 to the value of 0, with the `xPositions` given a new randomized value every reset.
- A second raindrop array is created with their own randomized `xPositions` value, but it won't create a third and a fourth, etc. I always only have a total of 2 raindrops at a randomized `xPositions` value.

```
var xPositions = [random(0, 400)]; //Randomized X position of raindrop
var yPositions = [0]; // Y position of raindrop

draw = function() {
    background(204, 247, 255);

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 200, 255);

    for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10); // for loop to create raindrop arrays

        if (yPositions[0] > 405) { //this is the part I am stuck on
            xPositions[0] = (random(0, 400));
            xPositions.push(random(0, 400));
            yPositions[0] = 0;
            yPositions.push(i);

        }
        yPositions[i] += 5;
    }

};
```

I tried to experiment around with the if statements but to no bug free avail.